# Como copiar uma linha específica de data frame para outro data frame

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Tenho seguinte Data Frame:

```
data = {
'País': ['Bélgica', 'Índia', 'Brasil','Índia','Bélgica','Bélgica','Russia','Brasil'],
'Capital': ['Bruxelas1', 'Nova Delhi', 'Brasília', 'Nova Delhi','Bruxelas2','Bruxelas3','Moscou','Brasília'],
'Continente': ['Europa', 'Asia', 'America do Sul', 'Asia','Europa','Europa','Europa','America do Sul'],
'População': [123465, 456789, 987654, 456789,123465,123465,350000000,987654]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['País','Capital','Continente','População'])

df1 = df.loc[0]
```

df1 é uma serie(pandas.core.series.Series).
.
Eu preciso que df1 seja data frame

Answer (score 1):

Olá,

Se você está tentando fazer um recorte do *dataframe* por índices, use `df.iloc[linha, coluna]`. O `loc` é usado quando você quer recortar com um nome de coluna ou um valor de linha.

Para converter uma `pandas.Series` em um `pandas.DataFrame`, basta chamar a função `pandas.Series.to_frame()` como explicado aqui na documentação: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.to_frame.html

Espero ter ajudado.